# Equation is locally singular, but Jacobian is not

Tags: matlab, singular

I have been using the Trust-Region Dogleg Method in MATLAB to solve a system of nonlinear equations: f(x)=c.  However, when I change the values of the c vector to certain values, MATLAB returns that the problem is locally singular.  When I outpu the jacobian, the determinant is about 1, so this matrix is not singular.  Is is possible to have a locally singular equation without a singular jacobian?

Comment: (Sounds more mathy than programmery.)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in the past that MATLAB gives this warning if you require extremely high accuracy (low tolerance). What are your tolerances? Can you give more info?

I apologize I didn't post this as a comment, but I don't have commenting privilleges yet. And I couldn't reach you via profile.